# ASP.NET Cannot detect parentheses in URL in some formats

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I do not know what this format with parentheses is called or what it is supposed to do or achieve: http://localhost/(A(somethinghere))/ displays the view at http://localhost/

I've been looking through Context.Request variables to try to find the (A(somethinghere)) but I haven't found it. It affects virtual paths though.

How do I detect this through Global.asax? What is this format called? What does it do?

Comment: In Global.asax you can catch the request at Application_BeginRequest event

Comment: I'm not looking for catching the request at that, I'm looking for finding (A(somethinghere)) specifically. It won't show up in things like PathAndQuery or AbsolutePath

Comment: Can you share how the request is appearing in AbsolutePath and PathAndQuery

Comment: Yeah. Context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery shows up as "/" when I go to /(A(A))/ , and Context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath is "/" as well.

Comment: Hi, I have tested thoroughly multiple times and I am receiving the url properly. Can you check and let me know.

Comment: According to your screenshot, you used lowercase A's. Can you try with Capital A's?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting it as answer, as I cannot add image in comment.

It's getting to Global.asax

[image]

Comment: I get "/" from RawUrl. It's so odd to me. If I go to localhost/Home/(A(AAA))/About I get /Home/About as well...

Comment: By the way, it only reacts this way IF the A is capital. Try with capital A's

Comment: I am trying to simulate, it looks any http module removing the url. UrlMappingsModule
ServiceModel-4.0
UrlRoutingModule-4.0
ScriptModule-4.0